# Change Material of one game object only using Ray cast and Mouse click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created the following code to see which game object i click but i cant find how to change the material of the object i click only, it changes the material of all objects which have the script.

```
//Public

public int TileGroup = 0; //Indicates the Tile Group Number.

//Private

public Rigidbody myRigidbody;
public Renderer myRenderer;
public Material tileDefaultMaterial;
public Material tileSelectedMaterial;
public Material tileSameGroupMaterial;

void Start () {
    myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    myRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer> ();
    tileDefaultMaterial = Resources.Load ("TileDefault", typeof(Material)) as Material;
    tileSelectedMaterial = Resources.Load ("TileSelected", typeof(Material)) as Material;
    tileSameGroupMaterial = Resources.Load ("TileSameGroup", typeof(Material)) as Material;
}

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        TileClick ();
    }
}

void TileClick (){

    RaycastHit hitInfo = new RaycastHit ();
    bool hit = Physics.Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition), out hitInfo);

    if (hit) {
        Debug.Log ("Hit: " + hitInfo.transform.gameObject.name);
    }

    if (hitInfo.transform.gameObject.tag == "Tile") {
        Debug.Log ("Hit a Tile!");
        myRenderer.material = tileSelectedMaterial;
    } else {
        Debug.Log ("Hit Empty Space!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call the `TileClick` method?

Comment: in void Update ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are running

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        TileClick();
    }
}
```

Whenever you click (no matter where), `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` will be true in all instances of scripts. So you end up changing color of all the objects.
Instead you can try the `OnMouseDown()` method.

```
void OnMouseDown() 
{
    TileClick();
}
```

Comment: That's not the problem myRenderer.material = tileSelectedMaterial; works fine. My problem is it changes the material for all game object that have the script in them. I want to change the material only on the game object i click.

Comment: Where do you assign MyRenderer. Would you care to share complete code?

Comment: Code is too long to paste here, http://image.prntscr.com/image/519857e6d5564942ac8570f750390818.png

Comment: check the new answer.

Comment: Thanks it works fine, It makes sense now because before using update and GetMouseButtonDown the code was getting called 27 times which made me a little suspicious that something is not right but i didn't think of OnMouseDown :).

Comment: You don't need to use raycast now. This one line should work. myRenderer.material = tileSelectedMaterial;